# Subset with data.table leaving NA's alone

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
    "A   B   D  E  iso   year   
     1   A   1  NA ECU   2009   
     2   B   2  0  ECU   2009   
     3   D   3  0  BRA   2011   
     4   E   4  0  BRA   2011   
     5   D   7  NA ECU   2008   
     6   E   1  0  ECU   2008   
     7   A   3  2  BRA   2012   
     8   A   4  NA BRA   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

I would like to remove the row where column `E` is `2`.

So I thought I could do: `dt<- setDT(dt)[E!=2]`, but this also removes the `NA`'s.

I guess I could first replace all the NA's with another number and then turn them back to NA's, but I would rather do it directly.

How do I tell `data.table` to leave the `NA` alone?

Desired output:

```
dt <- fread(
    "A   B   D  E  iso   year   
     1   A   1  NA ECU   2009   
     2   B   2  0  ECU   2009   
     3   D   3  0  BRA   2011   
     4   E   4  0  BRA   2011   
     5   D   7  NA ECU   2008   
     6   E   1  0  ECU   2008      
     8   A   4  NA BRA   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply extend your condition to

```
dt <- dt[E != 2 | is.na(E)]
```

Comment: I am not sure why I did not consider this haha. Anyway, thank you very much!